# How to retrieve uid according to that PhoneNumber while registration in Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[image: This is My Database image]

How do i Check Check in Database with User Entered Phone Number?

And i Want Notice to the User If he already registered.

```
String _getUserEnteredPhoneNumber = pNumber.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("People");

Query checkUser = reference.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(_getUserEnteredPhoneNumber);

checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            pNumber.setError("Username Exists,Please Enter Another User Name");
        } else {
           
             updateData();

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to query on the phone number, you need to specify that property in your call to `orderByChild()`. So:

```
Query checkUser = reference.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(_getUserEnteredPhoneNumber);
```

I highly recommend checking out the documentation on [sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data), which covers Firebase's query capabilities in more detail.

Comment: Can You Please help me out , Am suffering with  this problem since from 2 days

Comment: i implemented phone authentication ,and i stored the uid's in database when the user wants to register and want to check PhoneNumber In database, how do i check if the user is already registered or not

Comment: That's literally what I answered: you need to `orderByChild("phone")`, instead of `orderByChild("uid")` (which is what you currently do). Did you try the change?

Comment: i have a small doubt can you please the doubt, am suffering with many days ,

Comment: My scenario is: In  `Activity A` is User have to Enter The Phone Number Than I pass The phone Number To `Activity B` I send Code to The User than he/she Verify with Verification Code.Next In `Activity C` User Have to enter His Details But Unexpectedly he closed/backpressed the app From `Activity B` or From The `Activity C`..The Problem Is When he/she Re Launched The App he Redirected to `MainActivity` Without Entering His Details ....Because I Implemented CurrentUser SigIn Method...In `Activity A`, so The Conclusion Is I want To resume for 1min An `Activity B or C` like Where he left or Closed

Comment: and I want Display the same activity where he left within the 1min ...if he not relaunched the app within the time i have to sign out the current user.... this is the scenario i want to implement i hope you can suggest /help me

Comment: That seems like a different question, so I suggest opening a new post for it.

Comment: please Suggest me Anything which Useful to me ,,any documents please